# What should be the http error code if authorization is passed for preflight request Options method?

Tags: web-services, http, cors

I have a web service that requires authentication for GET request. Now for Options method we know that authentication is not requiref. But if someone still pass the authentication for Options method then what should be the http error code that we should returned?

Comment: The status code for the OPTIONS response should be 200 OK, regardless. It’s not clear what you’re actually asking, but if what your asking about is: What status code should the server respond with if it receives an OPTIONS request that has an Authorization header or that has some other form of authentication credentials, the then answer is that the server should response with a 200 OK. There’s no reason for the server to even check the response headers at all for an OPTIONS request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So for Options method I should always return with 200 irrespective of authentication is used or not @sideshowbarker

Answer (score 1):

Preflight request are meant for the browser to go ahead with actual request if http status code of `OPTIONS` are in `2XX` series.

So for most cases go ahead with any of the HTTP status code `200 , 204`.

For about CORS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS